# Java Hibernate get id of entity when insert username and password and delete it

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I want to get the auto-generated ID of already inserted entity to MySQL , I have an application made in javafx with hibernate , and I can't delete entity because the ID is autogenerated and I have to get the id of entity , so after I save it to database , then write the username and password I want it to give me the Id of inserted username and password .Let's say I already inserted the entity USERNAME : 123 , password : asd , and it get autogenerated the ID : 1. Now If i write in the fields username : 123 , password : asd and click delete button it should delete that entity..but it doesen't...so i need to get the ID of it and delete it by ID and I don't know how.

```
public class TestMain extends Application { 
     static Employee m = new Employee();

    public static void main(String[] args)  {  launch(args);   }  

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Stage window = primaryStage;

                window.setTitle("WELCOME");

                Label l1 = new Label();
                // l1.setFont(new Font(48));
                l1.setText("SMS");
                l1.setTranslateY(-180);                            

                Button closeBut = new Button("Exit.");
                closeBut.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Click to exit application"));
                closeBut.setOnAction(e -> window.close());
                Button save = new Button ("Save");
                save.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Click to save to database"));


                Label l2 = new Label("Username ");
                TextField username = new TextField();
                username.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Enter your new username"));
                username.setPromptText("username");
                GridPane.setConstraints(l2,0,0);
                GridPane.setConstraints(username,1,0);

                Label l3 = new Label("Password ");
                PasswordField password = new PasswordField();
                password.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Enter your new password"));
                password.setPromptText("password");
                GridPane.setConstraints(l3,0,1);
                GridPane.setConstraints(password,1,1);

                Label l4 = new Label();
                GridPane.setConstraints(l4,0,4);
                GridPane.setConstraints(save,0,2);
                GridPane.setConstraints(closeBut,1,2);              

                //Configureation Hibernate
               // Configuration config = new Configuration();
                //config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

                   SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

                 //  
                       save.setOnAction(e -> {
                       m.setUser(username.getText());
                       m.setPassword(password.getText());   

                       Session session = sf.openSession();   
                       session.beginTransaction();                                                                                       
                       session.delete(m);                      
                       session.getTransaction().commit();

                });

                GridPane grid = new GridPane();
                grid.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
                grid.setVgap(8);
                grid.setHgap(0);

                grid.getChildren().addAll(l1,l2,username,l3,password,save,l4,closeBut);
                grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                Scene scene = new Scene(grid,300,400);
                window.setScene(scene);
                window.show();

   }
}
```

And the java class employee :

```
package mypackage;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private int Id;


    @Column(name="USERNAME")
    private String user;

    @Column(name="PASSWORD")
    private String password;


    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    }
```

Comment: save.setOnAction.. so when this is clicked the user with specified usernmae and password is already in db right? And this button should remove it? Your case is a bit confusing i must say

Comment: I didn't made another button yet for delete , so when I insert I set session.save(m); and when i want to delete i change to session.delete(m);  , but It could be another button delete. I will make it , but I still can't delete an entity from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, I would go for a separate button, not to mix things.

So your save action would be:

```
save.setOnAction(e -> {
   m.setUser(username.getText());
   m.setPassword(password.getText());   

   Session session = sf.openSession();   
   session.beginTransaction();                                                                                       
   session.save(m);                      
   session.getTransaction().commit();
```

and your delete action would be:

```
delete.setOnAction(e -> {
   Session session = sf.openSession();   
   Transaction tx;

   try{
     tx = session.beginTransaction();

       Query query = session.createQuery("from Employee where user = :user and password = :password");
     query.setString("user", username.getText());
     query.setString("password", password.getText());

     Employee userToDelete = (Employee)query.uniqueResult();  

     session.delete(userToDelete );                      
     tx.commit(); 
   }catch(Exception e){
       tx.rollback();
   }finally{
        session.close();
   }
```

Comment: I tried this and every "querry" word is cut with a line and it says "Query is a raw type. References to generic type Query<R> should be parameterized" and doesen't work.

Comment: make sure you use org.hibernate.Query

Comment: In "User userToDelete = (User)query.uniqueResult();" User in my program should be Employee? It's refering to the Class?

Comment: yes of course it should be Employee.. my mistake , the answer is updated

Comment: Well , now it just gives me this in console "Mar 06, 2017 7:17:03 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory" and not deleting from database.

Comment: does it perform the query?

Comment: Yea, the query is working now, I needed to import org.hibernate.query.Query instead of org.hibernate.query because it was outdated or something like that. Now query works but still gives me that thing in console.

Comment: It's an INFO message only. Probably you have some high level of logging turned on

Comment: IT WORKS OMG! The problem was that here Query query = session.createQuery("from Employee where user = :user and password = :password"); Employee was writen like this and in Employee.class it was mapped like tahis : EMPLOYEE so it didn't recognise Employee mapped because it was EMPLOYEE OMG. Thank you kind sir! Now I`m going to get me a beer , sorry for taking your time.

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

The key here is the return value of the `session.save(m);` statement.

It will return the stored entity (including the generated key) which you then can use again to delete it

```
m = session.save(m); 
...
session.delete(m);
```